# Count number of rows in specific sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to count the number of rows for a specific sheet in Excel with PowerShell.

Here what I tried:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($fileList.Item($i))
$workbook.Sheets.Item(3).Activate()
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(3)
$rowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count
```

However, this is giving me the number of rows for the 1st sheet ... I wanted to get number of rows for the 3rd sheet.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(3)` -> `$worksheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet`

Comment: It doesn't work neither :(

Comment: It's working here. Line $workbook.Sheets.Item(3).Activate() is not necessary.

Comment: There was an error in my sheets, that why the count was incorrect.
Thank you guys for your help